# Access nested function closures in angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, closures, angular-services

I am trying to access a nested function inside a factory which I injected to a controller in AngularJS, but just get a 'function is undefined' error. I think the controller cannot even access to the inner function. Why?
Is this even legit JavaScript?

**The service**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule', [])
        .factory('myFactory', myFactory);

    function myFactory() {
        var outerVar = 0;

        function foobar() {
            var innerVar;

            function foo() {
                innerVar = outerVar++;
                console.log(innerVar);
            }

            function bar() {
                innerVar = outerVar--;
                console.log(innerVar);
            }

            return {
                foo: foo,
                bar: bar
            }
        }

        return {
            foobar: foobar
        }
    }
}());
```

**The controller**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    function myController(myFactory) {

        myFactory.foobar.foo();
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the foobar function, then it will return the desired object

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .controller('myController', myController);

    function myController(myFactory) {

        myFactory.foobar().foo();
    }
}());
```

Comment: Would it be better to use a `service` here instead of a `factory`? Perhaps it would be more elegant...

Comment: see, the difference between using a service and a factory is that if you use a factory , and when you inject that factory, angular will call the factory function and return to you the result i.e **foobar** object in this case. However , if you use a service and you inject it some where you will be provided with a new instance of the function i.e **new myFactory()**.

Comment: this link will be very helpful for you to decide which design pattern you should follow     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 1):

Just try :

```
myFactory.foobar().foo();
myFactory.foobar().bar();
```

It's the way it's intended to be used.